# What versions, if any, of the CXF server and client plugins are compatible with Grails 1.3.9?

Tags: grails, soap, cxf

Unfortunately we have an application running Grails 1.3.9 that is earmarked for upgrade soon.  However, before resources can be put into this upgrade we need to expose some of our services as SOAP endpoints.  We also need to interact with an external SOAP API.

Do versions of the following plugins exist that work with Grails 1.3.9?

- [cxf](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf)
- [cxf-client](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf-client)

If no such compatible versions exist, the wslite plugin looks like an attractive alternative for the cxf-client plugin.  Are there any such alternatives for the cxf plugin that can help expose services to SOAP requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the repo to see which plugin versions exist.  It would be nice to have a Grails script for this.

http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/cxf/

0.7 is the last version of the SOAP provider plugin that is Grails 1.x compatible, 1.6 is the last version of the plugin.

I've upgraded to Grails 2.x in the meantime so I haven't tested these, just didn't want to leave the question hanging.